# http service 503 unavailable Only for HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, azure

My azure website is working fine with http. Now, I have added a self-signed certificate and a binding in IIS 7. When I run the application with https, I get certificate error warning. When I confirm 'run anyway'. Then I get 'http service 503 unavailable' continuously only with https. My binding is correct(because I am seeing certificate error first time). No log found in IIS log files. Tried, IIS Failed-request tracing, no log found. I have confirm that iis user can register both port 80 and 443(using netsh). Any idea?

Edit: The site is now working if I use specific IP in binding. But when I chnage this to 'All Unassigned' I got the same error? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on above details it is not sure how it is done? Are you doing all of above RDP to Azure VM by manual binding or some startup process? Adding HTTPS endpoint to Azure Web Application is very easy and it should be done the pre-define process and there is nothing manual as you described above. This is how it is done:

1. Add an HTTPS Endpoint and bind a SSL certificate to it during development time in Windows Azure application
2. Deploy this SSL certificate (in PFX) to your "Certificate" section in Windows Azure Portal
3. Deploy your application to Windows Azure

How it works:

1. When Azure VM start the SSL certificate is provisioned to Windows Azure VM
2. Based on your Service Configuration and Definition settings IISConfigurator process include the certificate with your Web Application
3. When your web role starts, the binding are done based on Azure VM  internal IP address. "All assigned" is not used instead the binding is done to specific internal IP address.

My [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/28/complete-solution-adding-ssl-certificate-with-windows-azure-application.aspx) blog talk about how to add a HTTPS endpoint to Windows Azure application.

Comment: I think I have clearly said in update that the site is working with a https binding with specific IP but not working with 'All Unassigned' IP

Comment: Is it safe to bind with azure IP? What is the gurenteee that the ip will not change?

Comment: I am still puzzled that why there is a need for you to bind by yourself. When your web role is configured it is already done dynamically done. If you doing programmatically you can read the current IP using RoleEnvironment API and then bind it, this way you will get the correct internal IP.

Comment: I have a RDC(Remote Desktop Computer) where I configure my Azure's IIS.

Comment: That is a BIG NO and please don't do it. The Azure VM are not persisted so any change you will make to Azure VM over RDP will be discarded if Azure VM is recycled due to any reason. You should let this SSL Certificate done by application development time. Please follow my blog described above.

Comment: So, any setting in IIS will be lost if Azure VM recycled? if this is the case then why there is option of RDC in Windows Azure. Losing IIS setting will in Azure makes no sense. So, doing anything in RDC is dangerous?

Comment: Yes absolutely. RDP is only there to troubleshooting purposes and thats it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, greateful if you consider this as accepted solution.